# whichever player scores..or whichever person who scores

Tags: clauses

'**any** player **who** scores the highest number of points will be the winner.'

in above sentence,if we would replace whichever or whatever instead of any,can we use relative pronoun 'who' after whichever person or whatever person? like,
'**whatever** player **who** scores the highest number of points will be the winner.'

Comment: Or simply: "Whoever scores the highest number of points will be the winner."

Answer (score 2):

No, the pronoun *who* already is in your replacement:

> **Any** player **who** scores...

is equivalent to

> **Whoever** scores...
>   **Whichever** player scores...

The *who*, *which*, *what* in *whoever*, *whichever*, *whatever* already takes the role of the separate *who* in *any* ... *who*, so adding another *who* to your sentence means there is one pronoun too many.